# How can I make axios requests outside of module.exports with Azure Functions and node.js?

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-functions

I would like to make the consumption of an api through axios, using azure-functions and node.js

The issue occurs because I would like to put the request inside a function, but that function will be outside the module.exports.

Example:

```
module.exports = async function (context, request) {
    FN_ObteniendoInformacion({}, context)
}

const FN_ObteniendoInformacion= async (dataJson, context) => {
   //Axios Logic
})
```

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your Axios Logic as a method and call the method in the function, suppose your request still is within the function. Maybe you could refer to my code.

```
var axios = require('axios');  
var url='https://google.com'
const dorequest=function axiosTest( ) {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
      // returning the data here allows the caller to get it through another .then(...)

      return response;

    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
      })
  }

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    dorequest().then(function(response){
        console.log(response);

    });
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "ok"
    };

}
```

[image]